# Relationship between explored states and utilized memory in model-checking

Tags: model-checking, uppaal

What is possible relationship between states and utilized memory in model-checking. Can we estimate total memory that can possibly be utilized by our model (state space) before actually implementing it into the model-checker. can we roughly estimate minimum possible memory before actual implementation. On which factor memory utilization depend other than transitions and states.

ThankYou

Comment: I also would like to know, then we could implement it in Uppaal.